# How to build the 9 box icon for more apps such as in Google homepage

Tags: html, css

I was building the homepage of a search engine like Google's for learning and I'm stuck at making this:-

[image: The nine box icon]

Pls help me with the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be dumb but if you want to achieve it with pure css and html:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.more-apps {
  display: grid;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 0.2em;
  color: white;
}

.more-apps > * {
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<i class="more-apps">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find this on the Elements tab of the developer tool in the Chrome browser.

```
<svg class="gb_8e" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M6,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM16,6c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2s2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2zM12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Could you please explain the line or write it in a simpler way. That would be really helpful